# Google Spreadsheet API v3 - how to fetch an individual spreadsheet by id

Tags: google-sheets

So, the examples show you how to fetch a spreadsheet feed that gets ALL spreadsheets on the drive.

What is the format for setting the query.Uri? If i use entry.SelfUrl, or the following code, I get a 400 bad request

```
SpreadsheetQuery query = new SpreadsheetQuery();
query.Uri = new Uri(string.Format("{0}/{1}", DocumentsListQuery.documentsBaseUri, entry.ResourceId)); //400
// query.Uri = entry.SelfUri.Content; //also a 400
```

I also tried many different forms of the feed url, not least the one suggested by the one-page API documentation (replacing the `key` with the `ResourceId`, this actually returned a null feed, not a 400):

```
https://spreadsheets.google.com/feeds/worksheets/key/private/full
```

How do I fetch just one file?

Instead i am having to fetch all and query client-side:

```
 var feed = SpreadsheetFeedFor(query);
 var spreadsheet = (SpreadsheetEntry)feed.Entries.Single(e => e.SelfUri == resourceUri);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So, what is a spreadsheet other than a collection of Worksheets? Not much apparently, nothing discrete from a spreadsheet perspective - something with a filename, and you get that with the Docs API...soo, to get a spreadsheet, I've used the sample code that gets the worksheets for a given spreadsheet (by its drive's ResourceId / key):

```
        /// <summary>
        /// fetch a worksheet feed for a given spreadsheet
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="resourceId"></param>
        /// <returns></returns>
        protected WorksheetFeed WorksheetsFor(string resourceId)
        {
            var path = "https://spreadsheets.google.com/feeds/worksheets/{0}/private/full".Substitute(resourceId);
            WorksheetQuery query = new WorksheetQuery(path);
            WorksheetFeed feed = SpreadsheetsService.Query(query);
            return feed;
        }
```

Comment: Just FYI to anyone coming across this, for Auth 2.0, path should be the path of your spreadsheet.